# How to set the ID of a Dojo widget's inner input element?

Tags: javascript, widget, dojo

Dojo converts several "ordinary" input elements into a more complex node structure. For example, a Dojo `dijit/form/Select` results in a widget composed of a table instead of a `<select>` element. `dojox.form.Uploader` converts into something where the id is mapped to a `span` and not to a `<input id="myId" type="file"` element. etc etc.

For accessibility, I need to map a label to an input widget, and running my website through [Wave](http://wave.webaim.org/) generates a lot of red flags because label `for` values do not match an input `id`.

What's the best way round this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `id` property on *most* widgets, which should be put on the inner `<input>` node that you desire. Take a [look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Zh8/61/) for an example. If you open up your HTML inspector for the TextBox widget, you will see that the outer node has an `id` of "widget_[my id]" and a `widgetid` of the id you passed to the widget. Digging into the contents of that outer div, you will see that the actual `<input>` element indeed has the desired id that I passed in.

However, it seems that for more complex widgets that use a hidden `<input>` to store the value, you have to explicitly set the id of the `valueNode` property. You can see an example [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Zh8/62/).

So you can create your widget like programmatically like this:

```
var select = new Select({
  ... widget properties
});
select.valueNode.id = "my_id"; // probably best to use dom-attr to set this.
```

If your widget is created declaratively, then you will need to get access to it via the registry, an attach point, or dijit#byId.

Comment: Thanks - I've been trying with the id declared as a separate attribute
`<input id="myId" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select`.

Comment: Update: nope doesn't work. id is mapped again to outer table, not an `input` element

Comment: Interesting. I guess it does not work the same way with widgets that have a hidden input such as `Select`. However there is an alternative way to do this. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - for the select and uploader widgets I'm planning to extend them and use a modification of your idea, probably by adding a unique `forid` attribute so they can be used declaratively. I'm marking your post as an accepted answer though.